# How to load tree store with data from another tree store reader

Tags: extjs

I have couple of tree panels, each configured with individual tree stores. I have configured a proxy for one store. on load event of this, i am trying to load the second store(proxy memory) like below. But doesn't work.

Ext version: 4.0.7

```
_treeStore2 = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
model: 'Scenario',
proxy : {
type : 'memory'
}

});

_treeStore1 = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
model: 'Scenario',
root:'data1',
proxy : {
type : 'ajax',
url: '/proj/examples?id='+_Id,
reader : {
type : 'json',
root:'data1'
}
},
listeners: {
'load': {
fn: function(store, records, success, operations) {
_treeStore2.setRootNode(_treeStore1.getProxy().getReader().jsonData.data2);
}
}
});
```

Sample JSON data:

```
 {"data1":[{"name":"value","children":[]}],"data2": [{"name":"value","children":[]}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the raw Json data, try just passing the the "records" param from the load listener to the other Store. So something like this:

```
listeners: {
    load: function(store, records) {
        _treeStore2.setRootNode.setRootNode(records);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/**
 * Because of a bug in Ext.data.NoteInterface in ExtJs < 4.1.3
 * we have to do deep cloning.
 */
var clone = function(node) {
  var result = node.copy(),
      len = node.childNodes ? node.childNodes.length : 0,
      i;
  // Move child nodes across to the copy if required
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    result.appendChild(clone(node.childNodes[i]));
  return result;
};

var oldRoot = store1.getRootNode(),
    newRoot = clone(oldRoot);

store2.setRootNode(newRoot);
```